# Find all rows according to criteria

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

Could you please help me. How to extract all the rows which matches criteria, INDEX and MATCH show just first row and I need to see all the rows.
Will appreciate any help.

Comment: Welcome to Super User! What have you tried so far? What research have you done? :)

Comment: Your question is quite unclear, unfortunately, and it's really hard to give you an appropriate answer. Please provide more information about what you need to do, what you already tried, the expected outcome... A screenshot can often help!

Comment: Regarding your issue: what about a pivot table? It's often the easiest way to return rows based on a set of criteria, as well as synthesize data.

Comment: A simple filter might also do the job, hiding all rows that do not have the required criteria

Comment: Please edit the Question and upload the Formula you have worked with will help us to fix it and find the criteria also.

Comment: If I'm not wrong you are expecting Excel to return more that one row which meets the criteria !!

Answer (score 1):

If you use **0** as column index in the **INDEX** function, you get the whole row. For example;

```
=INDEX(C3:E7,2,0)
```

formula returns 2nd row in C3:E7 range. This formula returns #VALUE! error if it isn't an array formula. However, you can use it in another function that can use arrays. For example;

```
=SUM(INDEX(C3:E7,2,0))
```

Alternatively; you can use the **OFFSET** function with *row* and *column* arguments. Such as;

```
=OFFSET(B2,2,0,1,COLUMNS(B6:H6))
```

function returns 3rd row (because of its 2nd argument).

Here is more detailed information: [How to return an entire row](https://www.spreadsheetweb.com/how-to-return-entire-row/)

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know `INDEX` could be used like this. Very useful!

Comment: @piko I personally prefer to leave out the `0`, i.e., `=INDEX(C3:E7,2,)`. That better reminds me that I'm getting an array result.

Comment: **#FezzikMontoya**, your formula =INDEX(C3:E7,2,0) will return #Value error since in the formula ZERO representing Column and it should not be 0, for this formula Column count starts from 1. Your Formula should be written like {=INDEX(C3:E7,2,0)}.

Comment: @RajeshS Thanks for the comment. You are right if user wants to use the formula alone. However, it will be meaningful in a another function like **SUM** or **AVERAGE**. I will add this information to my answer as well. Thanks.